# Spotfire: Average of the average in Grand Total of Cross Table

Tags: crosstab, spotfire

Can Spotfire perform an "average over an average" using Cross tables? I'm hitting a problem where I want each row to show an average over the a particular model. However, for the grand total of the cross table, I actually want it to calculate the average of the averages of the rows. Here's an example:

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RURyZ.png)

[image]

You can see that in the row aggregations, that for Model A, the average is 1. And for Model B, the average is two. I want the grand total aggregation to be the average of 1 and 2 which is 1.5 (i.e. the "average of the averages"), not 1.33 (the true average of the data).

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Put your example directly in the question. Links die over time.

Comment: I just started today. I can't embed pictures yet. Do you have any advice on my question?

Comment: I have no experience with Spotfire. I had assumed your example link was to text. sorry about that.

Comment: There's a requested edit to put the image in, it should pass soon.

Answer (score 1):

@lenzinip- Instead of converting the existing table to a cross table, create a new data table/replace the existing table by adding pivot transformation.

The reason for this step is, though you are converting the existing table to a cross table and calculating average, it sums the total i.e., 4 and divides by 3 [number of rows] which is 1.33 [4/3]. Though the cross table displays only two rows (one per model), the underlying table has 3 rows.

When you create a cross table, it sums the average 3 and divides by 2 as there are now 2 row items instead of 3.

[image]

Now, in the cross table add `avg(avg([total]))`. This should give you the desired result.

*Note: You can add pivot transformation directly on the existing table without creating a new data table. I have created a separate table for explanation purpose.*

Hope this helps!